# Magento 2: Why is rebuilding config.php from CLI failing with 'Invalid Base URL'?

Tags: magento2, core-config-data

To set the background I am using Magento 2.3.0 and have imported (successfully so far) data from an existing multi-store site. I now can't access either the front end or the admin area of the site since the config has now changed and Magento throws an Exception requesting I rebuild `config.php`. The problem started when I changed a config key from the command line (the admin frontend URL).

Now when I try to rebuild /etc/config.php using

```
php bin/magento app:config:import
```

I receive the error 
`Import failed: Invalid Base URL. The value must be a URL or one of the placeholders: {{base_url}}`
... which incidentally is a pretty feeble error message as it doesn't even indicate which key is causing the problem.

After stepping through the code I can see *one* of the offending keys is `web/unsecure/base_web_url` for the `default` scope which is causing the problem since in Magento 2 core post config read processing it is returning `http:///` which clearly *is* an invalid URL. This is despite the fact that in my database (in core_config_data) there is an entry for that path and scope with a valid URL (which *does* end with a trailing /).

Stepping deeper into the code I can see the problem is that `module-store/Model/Config/Placeholder` is calling `/App/Request/Http->getDistroBaseUrl()` which uses the PHP Server variable `['HTTP_HOST']` to determine the host which is blank when called from the command line and hence returns the `http:///`.

If anyone can shed *any* light on how this can be resolved I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Similar issue in the past was all down to cache ended up deleteing var/cache /generation and running setup upgrade after which worked fine make sure that parameter is set and valid in the database before as config is cached in magento 2

Comment: Thanks Dava, I should have thought of that! Although, to be fair, the symptom was, typically, perplexingly obscure.

Comment: Glad its working will post as answer now so you can mark as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar issue in the past was all down to cache in your CLI run the following

```
rm -rf var/cache/ generation/
```

After you have done the above run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deplpoy
```

You may need to force the deployment process you can do that by adding -f to the end over the second command

after which worked fine make sure that parameter is set and valid in the database before as config is cached in magento 2